# How do I run avalanchego with a local version of coreth?

Tags: geth, avalanche

I forked coreth and added some custom functions. I want to compile and run avalanchego with this custom coreth but have been having issues.

In the coreth documentation there are short instructions for running avalanchego with a local coreth here https://github.com/ava-labs/coreth#building . But after following these instruction - when trying to run the built ./scripts/avalanchego I get the error

```
couldn't load process config: couldn't find valid build directory in any of the default locations: [/folder/avalanchego/build /folder/avalanchego /folder/avalanchego /usr/local/lib/avalanchego /home/myname/.avalanchego]
```

When I try building the docker image after following the instructions in coreth#building using ./scipts/build_image I get

```
go mod download: github.com/ava-labs/coreth@v0.8.7-rc.2 (replaced by /folder/coreth): reading /folder/coreth/go.mod: open /folder/coreth/go.mod: no such file or directory
```

suggesting that my custom coreth does not have a go.mod file - but I can confirm it does. Asking if anyone can identify what next steps could be taken given this information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `plugins` directory in same directory where `avalanchego` resides.